# C# MySql connector library stored in project?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem. I Downloaded the MySql connector, then added to my project via the reference and .NET... I sent the project to a friend, so he can test it. But the connector is on my PC, so he don't have the MySql.Data library. The question is, how can I import it into the project fully, so if I send it to somebody, the program stores the library and it is fully useable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Copy Local` of the `MySQL.Data` reference to `true`:

[image]

This will include the MySQL.Data.dll assembly in your project's output folder. You'll need to include it if you intend to distribute your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to test it out now.